# Textfield not displaying in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am trying to display a textfield in a column of ng2-smart-table component.
Referred [ng2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation) documentation but still textfield is not showing. Could you please help to solve this issue.
[image]
In component.ts file:

```
setting = {
    multimode:true,
    hideSubHeader:true,
    actions: false,
    columns: {
        NAME: 
        {
        title: 'Name'
        },

        VALUE: {
            title: 'Value',
            type:'text',
            editor:{
                type:'text'

            }

         }
        },
        attr: 
        {
        class: 'table table-bordered'
        }
    }
```

In component.html file:

```
 <ng2-smart-table [settings]="setting" [source]="ConfigureSource" ></ng2-smart-table>
```

In ConfigureSource.ts file:

```
export const ConfigureData: Array<any> = [
        {
                  "Name": "John",
                  "Value": ""

              },
              {
                  "Name": "Sam",
                  "Value": ""
              }

          ];
```

Comment: Can you post an example of configureSource?

Comment: @EhsanKiani added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set the actions:

> actions: { edit: true, position: 'right' }

and the **column editable to true**

Comment: @JobyWilsonMathews, if you set a column editable false does it still editable?